# Optimal Transport Theory: Find a sequence of functions that converge weakly to 1/2

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, optimal-transport

**I'm trying solve the following problem:**

Find a sequence $T_n$ of transport maps from $\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}dx$ to $\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}dx$ such that $T_n$ converges weakly to $\frac{1}{2}$. Deduce that the weak limit of transport maps need not be a transport map. *Hint:* take $T_n$ to be a piecewise linear sawtooth function.

**I was told to use the following sequence**

$$
T_n(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}2^{n-1}\left(x-\frac{j}{2^{n-1}}\right)\mathbb{I}_{\Big[\frac{j}{2^{n-1}},\frac{j+1}{2^{n-1}}\Big)}(x)\text{ and }T_n(1)=1.
$$

**Could anyone please help me with this exercise?** That is

- a). How do I prove that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}, T_n$ is a pushforward for Lebesgue measure over** $[0,1]$? I.E.

$$
T_{\#\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}}=\mathbb{I}_{[0,1]}.
$$

- b). How do I prove the weak convergence to 1/2?

Comment: What space do you require your $T_n$ to be in? What is your notion of weak convergence here?

Comment: The $T_n$ should be in $L^2([0,1])$ and $T_n\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$ weakly if for all $g\in L^2([0,1])$ we have that $\int_0^1 g(x)\left(T_n(x)-\frac{1}{2}\right)dx\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), under the $\pi-\lambda$ Theorem, it suffices to prove $\mathcal{L}_{[0,1]}(T_n^{-1}([a,b]))=\mathcal{L}_{[0,1]}([a,b])$ for all intervals $[a,b]\subset[0,1]$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ (here $\mathcal{L}_{[0,1]}$ is the Lebesgue measure restricted to [0,1]). Based on the definition of your $T_n$, this should be obvious by observing that the inverse image of an interval under $T_n$ is a disjoint union of smaller intervals with a total length equal to $[a,b]$. Maybe it is a good idea to plot the function for a few small $n$.

For (b), first note the integral of $T_n$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Then since $L^2([0,1])$ is a reflexive Banach space, any norm-closed ball is weakly sequentially compact, which means that given any subsequence $\{T_{n_j}\}$ of $\{T_n\}$, we have a further subsequence $\{T_{n_{j_k}}\}$ that weakly converges to a function $f$ in $L^2([0,1])$. By choosing the test function to be 1, one can show that $f$ is always $\frac{1}{2}$, which shows that the original sequence converges weakly to $\frac{1}{2}$ itself, thus concluding the proof.

Comment: Could you please explain explain thoroughly what you did on part **b)**?

Comment: @VicMignonia Can you specify the point you feel confused about?

Comment: I mean, cannot you use an $L^2([0,1])$-norm/Holder inequality argument and taking limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: @VicMignonia If I understand correctly, for that, you need to have $||T_n(x)-1/2||_{L^2([0,1])} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, but $||T_n(x)-1/2||_{L^2([0,1])}$ is a non-zero constant for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.